# How to use the windows waitfor utility

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Windows 7 and later include a utility called "waitfor.exe".  The program is supposed to listen and wait for a named signal to be received.  It also can send a signal.

The syntax for waiting for a signal is something like:  `waitfor.exe somevent`

The syntax for sending is supposed to be: `waitfor.exe /S remotecomputer /SI somevent`.  There are also options for specifying a user and password to connect to a remote computer.

But I am having trouble getting this to work.  The program appears to work okay when waiting for a signal.  But I have never been able to get the program to work in send mode.

I've tried these possibilities:

- `waitfor /si someevent` - produces error - ERROR: Unable to send signal 'someevent'.
- `waitfor /s someevent` - syntax error
- `waitfor /s %COMPUTERNAME% someevent` - syntax error
- `waitfor /s %COMPUTERNAME% /si someevent` - produces error - ERROR: Unable to send signal 'someevent'.

I want to use this program to simply synchronize between two command windows, running as the same user.  Neither is running elevated.  Testing in this scenario produces the above errors.

I know I can find (or write) 3rd party utilities to do this, but I would like to use a windows built-in utility.  I also would like to avoid using powershell, as its performance is poor, for my use case.  Also also also, I know I can cobble together a synchronization mechanism using "if exist" on the receive side, plus creating a file on the send side (ditto for the registry, using reg.exe), but I'd like to avoid that also.  The latency of such solutions is inversely proportional to performance (the receive side would need to use a polling loop).

Does anyone know how to make waitfor.exe work for this simple same-computer same-user scenario ?  Or any other built-in with good performance and zero latency?

---

exact detail of error messages:

```
C:\>where waitfor
C:\Windows\System32\waitfor.exe

C:\>rem - did run "waitfor myevent" in another window

C:\>waitfor /s %COMPUTERNAME% /si myevent
ERROR: Unable to send signal 'myevent'.

C:\>waitfor /s %COMPUTERNAME% myevent
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "WAITFOR /?" for usage.

C:\>
```

My computer is running Windows 2008 R2 server, and is part of a corporate active directory domain.

---

Comment: What happens if you use a user name and password? `WAITFOR /S %PCNAME% /U %UNAME% /P %UPASS% /SI %SIGNAL%` Additionally, I'd suggest you provide more specific information about what signal you are trying to send and sync between each.

Comment: I've just noticed what you're trying to achieve and I'm not even sure that `WaitFor` allows to send across a network to itself. Have you had any success with a very basic signal such that you are sure that this even works?

Comment: waitfor.exe is based on [mailslots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365576). `waitfor someevent` creates a mailslot named `\\.\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\someevent`. Sending the signal via `waitfor /si someevent` opens a handle for `\\*\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\someevent`, where "*" has the UNC provider broadcast the message to every computer on the domain. `waitfor /s %COMPUTERNAME% /si someevent` specifically opens `\\[computer_name]\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\someevent` instead of broadcasting the signal.

Comment: I've edited the post to add output of where, plus a screen-scrape of the errors.

Comment: I have tested this on several other computers, and it's failed on all but one of them.  So it could be that waitfor is simply not reliable, and perhaps should not be used for any batch script outside of a very specific scenario on a single computer.

Comment: `waitfor /s %COMPUTERNAME% myevent` is invalid. The `/s` option is used with `/si` to send the signal to a specific machine instead of broadcasting it. Sending the signal is failing with a vague error message, so there isn't much I can do to help without using a crystal ball.

Comment: You can get more info with WinDbg, configured with Microsoft's symbol server. Have it run `waitfor /si myevent`. Set a breakpoint (`bp`) on `waitfor!CWaitFor::PerformOperations`. Begin (`g`). When it breaks in, set another breakpoint on `kernelbase!CreateFileW` and resume (`g`). When it breaks in, confirm the filepath via `du @rcx`. If it's the mailslot, continue to the return via `pt`. Check the return value (`r rax`). If it's -1 (i.e. all Fs in hexadecimal), then check the last error value via `?? @$teb->LastErrorValue`. Get the error message using `!error [hexadecimal error code]`.

Comment: @eryksun , I used procmon to look at the difference between the success case and the failure case.  waitfor uses CreateFile to create the mailslot object, this works for both cases.  waitfor then uses WriteFile to write several bytes to the mailslot.  For the success case, the return from WriteFile is "SUCCESS", but the failure case, the return is "DISCONNECTED".  Also, waitfor uses a prefix of "\\*\" as opposed to "\\.\", it looks as if there is no wait for it to run "local only".  This may be the problem, but whichever, I think it makes waitfor inappropriate for script synchronization.

Comment: As I already said, creating the Mailslot uses `\\.\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\[event name]`, i.e. the Mailslot is always created on the local machine. When it opens it to send the signal it defaults to using `\\*\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\[event name]` to broadcast sending the signal, but you can use the `/s` option to open the Mailslot on a specific system, including the local machine, in which case it instead opens `\\[computer_name]\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\[event name]`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something is not right on your system.  This works fine for me, using normal command prompt windows (not running with Administrative rights).

I opened a couple of command windows on my laptop.  In the first, I typed "waitfor somevent".  It commenced to wait.  In the second, I typed "waitfor /si somevent" which gave a message "SUCCESS: Signal sent" and the waitfor command in the first command window then terminated.

I tried a second time, doing the same thing in the first window (waitfor somevent).  In the second window I typed "waitfor /s ots-jburd-ltOTS-JBURD-LT /si somevent" (where ots-jburd-lt is the name of my laptop), and again, the waitfor in the first window terminated as expected.

I logged into my home network and ran some quick tests there, and everything worked as expected (sending 'somevent' from one computer to another).

My tests show that your syntax is correct.  You report that a simple "waitfor /si someevent" fails with the message "ERROR: Unable to send signal 'someevent'".  This does not happen on my machines.  (And the posted question is on how to use the waitfor command.)

I'm not sure what can prevent a signal from being sent.  Most likely a firewall setting?  But my laptop is running on a public network right now, and all my defenses are at 100%, and it works on my laptop with no problems.  Maybe you have some other 3rd-party anti-malware running which prevents signals from being sent?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code that implements your example:

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%1" neq "" goto %1


rem Start a Send - Receive pair
start "" /B "%~F0" Send ^> pipefile.txt
call "%~F0" Receive < pipefile.txt
echo Program ending.
goto :EOF


:Send
set "line="
set /P "line=Enter a line, EXIT to end: " > CON
echo %line%
waitfor /SI dataAvailable > NUL
if /I "%line%" neq "EXIT" goto Send
echo Send part ending... > CON
exit /B


:Receive
waitfor dataAvailable > NUL
set /P "data="
echo Data received: "%data%"
if /I "%data%" neq "EXIT" goto Receive
echo Receive part ending...
exit /B
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test> test.bat
Enter a line, EXIT to end: Line one
Data received: "Line one"
Enter a line, EXIT to end: Second line sent to receive part
Data received: "Second line sent to receive part"
Enter a line, EXIT to end: exit
Data received: "exit"
Receive part ending...
Program ending.

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test> Send part ending...
```

Windows 8.1 here.